# Vue.js renders code inside braces literally - shows braces instead of the result

Tags: vue.js

This is my `<template>` code:

```
<div class="message-details pull-right small" style="display: none;">
  <strong>Intent:</strong> {{ message.intent }} ({{ (message.confidence * 100).toFixed(2) + '%' }})
  <br>
  <strong>Entities:</strong>
  {{ message.entities.map(e => `${e.type} = ${e.value}`).join('<br>') }}
  ...
  other stuff
```

It renders as follows:

[image]

As you can see, instead of computing the second expression inside the brackets, it is rendered literally, while the first expression works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{{ message.entities.map(e => e.type = e.value).join('\r\n') }}
```

And Can you post the console error that appears when you run the code ?

Comment: there's nothing on the console actually